# Core Data and Magical Record saving

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

This is somewhat of a basic question, but need some clarification.

I have this piece of code.

```
   //line of code #1

[localContext MR_saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {

   //line of code #2

}];
```

Is the line of code #2 the completion block?  Should I make my changes to an entity prior to the save as line of code #1 shows?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything with the form of `^(…) { … }` or `^{ … }` is a [block](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxGettingStarted.html). In essence, a block is portable a chunk of code which is not directly executed. A block can be saved to a variable then execute at a later point in time.

```
typedef void (^my_block_t)();
my_block_t myBlock = ^{
    NSLog(@"I'm in a block");
};
```

Here's a block which prints a log statement. The block is saved to the variable `myBlock`. Note: at this point in time, `NSLog` does not print out anything.

At some point in time later, `myBlock` can be execute.

```
myBlock();
```

At this point in the code, the block is run and `NSLog` prints out it's statement.

If your example, the execution of line of code #2 is delayed until after the save has completed.

Logically, it works the same as:

> Step 1) execute line of code #1
>   Step 2) execute save
>   Step 3) execute line of code #2

Because things in line of code #2 happen after the save has completed, then any changes to the model would not be saved at that point.